# How to use jquery contains:selector to a div and display a different div block when matched?

Tags: jquery, xml, contains

I'm having issues with a consolidated code that I'm working on.

Reference: 
http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/children/

Problem: I'm using jquery contains:selector to match keywords (from variable) into a specific DIV (class="keywords"). If there's a match, then display another DIV (class=display) without the keywords DIV text.

Another problem, is that when variable keyword has a match with DIV (class=display), then it display the DIV (class=display) - but it shouldn't because I wanted to restrict it to the DIV (class=keywords) only.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">San Antonio Spurs</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for SAS</div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Miami Heat</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results two for MIA</div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Los Angeles Lakers</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results three for LAL</div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Cleveland Cavaliers</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results two another for CAVS</div>
</div>
```

Here's the script -

```
var keyword= "Spurs";

$('.container').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":contains("+keyword+")")){
        $(this).children(".display").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

I'm trying to use .children, or altering the code, but to no avail.

Here are my test cases -

1. Keyword = Spurs, then display = Results one for SAS (correct result)
2. Keyword = Cleveland, then display = Results two another for CAVS (correct result)
3. Keyword = SAS, then do not display anything (BUT on my code it's incorrect)
4. Keyword = LAL, then do not display anything (BUT on my code it's incorrect)

The problem with #3 and #4, it still displays the DIV (class=display)

Here's my testing fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/m6swkksg/14/

Any help will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit your search to `.keywords` only

```
var keyword= "Spurs";
$('.container').has('.keywords:contains('+keyword+')').children(".display").show();
```

In your case, you are checking the contents of the whole `.container` element against the keyword which will check the contents of the `display` element also which is not what you want.

```js
$('input').change(function () {
    $('.container .display').hide();
    
    var keyword = this.value;
    $('.container').has('.keywords:contains(' + keyword + ')').children(".display").show();
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input value="Spurs" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="keywords" style="display:none">San Antonio Spurs</div>
    <div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for SAS</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Miami Heat</div>
    <div class="display" style="display:none">Results two for MIA</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Los Angeles Lakers</div>
    <div class="display" style="display:none">Results three for LAL</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Cleveland Cavaliers</div>
    <div class="display" style="display:none">Results two another for CAVS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun P Johny it worked! - got a new test here - http://jsfiddle.net/gw7v2b8x/

I missed that .has, but now it looks correct with my test cases.

Comment: @syntaxcode you can use the new snippet from SO instead of jsfiddle as I have attached above

Comment: Thanks for that new code snippet tool. Nice! I can check my keyword tests!

Answer (score 0):

Try to ignore the `.display` element, when invoking `.is()` over `.container`, that would search for a match in all of its descendants.

```js
var keyword= "Spurs";
$('.container > .keywords:contains('+ keyword +')').next('.display').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">San Antonio Spurs</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for SAS</div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Miami Heat</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results two for MIA</div>
</div>
    
<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Los Angeles Lakers</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results three for LAL</div>
</div>
    
<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Cleveland Cavaliers</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results two another for CAVS</div>
</div>
```

If you are in a confusion to use the inbuilt demo, just have a look at [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6swkksg/15/).

Comment: Thanks @Rajaprabhu Aravindasam, this one worked too. Got the Reference for this: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/next/